# How can I mod Crusader Kings 2 to prevent vassals from declaring Holy Wars?

Tags: crusader-kings-2-modding

I would like to have a playthrough where my vassals cannot declare wars.

I have set "vassal_wars_law_2" to all my subordinate kingdoms, and yet, this regularly happens:

[image]

I think that to prevent this I have to modify something in the

```
# Regular Holy War CB
religious = {
    name = CB_NAME_RELIGIOUS
    war_name = WAR_NAME_RELIGIOUS
```

declaration in the **00_cb_types.txt** file.

Unfortunately I am quickly out of my depth and I don't know exactly what to change to disable that Casus Belli type for everyone in my empire except me, the emperor.

Can someone please help me in understanding the necessary steps?

Comment: I've been told that this question should be on topic ( https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51359117#51359117 ) If I have not given enough details, please let me know so that I can edit them in.

Comment: It is on topic although I’m not sure how big the relevant audience is here. Have you tried asking on forums dedicated to the game itself?

Comment: @Josh I'm hesitant to use game forums, and so I would like to try here first.